# Getting error while starting the windows service

Tags: sql, nhibernate, exception

```
WARN  NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'X'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.Impl.BatcherImpl.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
```

x table exist in my database with dbo which I read from various forums.THis kind of error never happened in test env. but happened in Production which is web farm.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sql profiler on and see what the credentials service is logging on as. Check that that user has rights to see the objects in the DB.

You need to determine what is missing. Is it the data or access to the data? Can you login to the server from the production server and get the data from the command line? SQLCMD or osql should be there is the SQL client it installed

Comment: i don't have sql profiler.And we are using nhibernate so cna't see the query